# Импорт *.csv файла в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$import = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/sata2/home/users/xn80akhml/www/test.xn--80akhmlofgv.net/database_EDRSR/regions.csv' INTO TABLE edrsr FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' optionally ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (region_code, name)";
$mysqli->query($import);
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
```

Ошибка: "Access denied for user ....."

Пробую так

```
if (($handle = fopen("database_EDRSR/documents.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($dataFile = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
            $value .= "('".$dataFile[0]."', '".$dataFile[1]."'),";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
$values = substr($values, 0, -1);
 $insert = "INSERT INTO edrsr_documents (doc_id, regions) VALUES $values";
    $mysqli->query($insert);
```

Вставляется только половина и ошибка

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14645586 bytes) in
или 
504 Gateway Time-out

csv файл 500000 строк. Каждый день добавляются новые строки, изменяются имеющиеся. Нужно импортировать каждый день. К концу года будет около 5000000 строк. Подскажите как правильно импортировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Может не быть привилегии доступа `FILE` (можно проверить, выполнив запрос [`SHOW GRANTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html))
2. Есть привилегия, но установлена переменная `secure_file_priv` и файл лежит не в указанной директории (или переменная установлена в `NULL` - тогда `LOAD FILE` будет отключен)

См. также

1. [Системные переменные сервера (secure_file_priv)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) (по-английски)
2. [Привилегии (FILE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) (по-английски)
3. [Синтаксис `GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) (по-английски)

Comment: Привилегия FILE отключена так как небезопасна

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov `secure_file_priv` - делает эту проблему гораздо менее острой